# Passport cover page

Tags: visas, air-travel, passport-stamps, damaged-passports

You can see condition of cover page of my passport. Let me know is there any issue for getting visa or international travel. I have already applied business visa of Thailand. [image]

Comment: See [Should we add a indian-passport-damage tag? - Travel Meta Stack Exchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8402/95267)

Comment: My fiance has a similar problem in Thailand. She was travelling back home. The girl at the airport said that she agreed to flight because we were returning home, if not she had to refuse.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - if the ID page is separated from rest of the passport - it is damaged. You have to renew.

The smudges are fine and expected.

Comment: I'd page is not separate from rest of passport.. thread is holding cover with passport. There is only one Crack line near the thread.

Comment: That should be fine.